# json_encode() removes attributes (PHP)

Tags: php, json, xml, simplexml

I am using `json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml))` in PHP 7.0.10 to convert some XML-Code into JSON. The following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<comments count="6">
<comment id="1" active="1" object="1" user="1" created="1473776866" updated="1473776866">Something</comment>
<comment id="2" active="1" object="1" user="2" created="1473776866" updated="1473776866">Hello</comment>
<comment id="3" active="1" object="1" user="3" created="1473776866" updated="1473776866">Just a comment</comment>
<comment id="6" active="0"/>
</comments>
```

creates the following result:

```
{"comments":{"@attributes":{"count":"6"},"comment":    
["Something","Hello","Just a comment", {"@attributes":{"id":"6","active":"0"}}]}}
```

Can someone explain me what's happening with all the attributes of the `<comment>`s?

Thanks, I appreciate any help!

EDIT: I figured out that all the attributes of an XML element are dropped whenever the given node has just a text value: `<something attribute="will be dropped">just text</something>`. 
So for the moment I am using an ugly workaround: I've modified the code in a way that it replaces all the strings occurrences with `<text>string</text>` before giving the XML to `simplexml_load_string()`. This solution works fine for the moment, but I'm still interested in a cleaner one …

Comment: Thats not json  data use `simplexml_load_string()`! In `json` they are no `attributes` or `nodes`, just `array` or `objects with fields` ....

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: I'm already using simplexml_load_string(). 
(Sorry, forgot to mention that. I've updated the question.)

Comment: Yep, have noticed that. You got an tricky thing here :)

Comment: @PaulCrovella SimpleXML isn't a bad API, but it is a bad *choice* of API for blindly converting XML into JSON, which is, frankly, a weird thing to do. It's a great API for *actually doing things with the XML data*, like using the values in your control flow or in a template.

Comment: @Paul Crovella Did you mean with _above_:  namespaces and other stuff? One thing i noticed was, when i parsed a 1GB xml it uses 10GB memory :) I used the PARSE_HUGH flag. But SimpleXML is tricky and funny like all stuff in PHP

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Regarding memory usage, it's just a wrapper around "libxml2", which is completely independent of PHP. It doesn't actually create any native PHP objects until you access nodes. And a serialized:unserialized ratio of 1:10 doesn't seem too bad (it's hardly going to use *less* memory than the serialized version!). Once you're in that range, you really need an event-based parser - which PHP also provides, also built on libxml2.

Comment: @Manuel, you've done the right thing enclosing the comment into another mark withoud attributes. Take a look of your sample at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0tnf-e1w2

Answer (score 0):

Your json output shows the last id of the last comment. So `json_encode()` overides the "comment" an each iteration. You have to prepare your `xml` Data, before you can give it to `json_decode()`. So parse the XML into an Object `simplexml` and then create an php array from that, so you can then `encode` that array. I dont think you get a **one-liner-solution** here ;)

To your question:
**Can someone explain me what's happening with all the attributes of the comments?**

The are no missing `attributes`, the `<comment>`s from 1-5 dont show up in the json.

UPDATE: Sry, didnt see this part `"Something","Hello","Just a comment",`, and that is really wired. All comments are there,but in the same array are the attributes!?!? And attributes itself is an object!?
You have to prepare it by yourself like i sayed above. No way around. You can not depand on a result from json_encode(simpelxml_load_string('XML')), SimpleXML is not made for that!

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is not built for this kind of blind conversion. It doesn't create a neat array that you can convert into JSON, and actually creating a JSON format that neatly encapsulates all the possible structures of XML is tricky (and IMHO pretty pointless).

The method invoked when you run `json_encode` like this is mostly intended for debugging (note that `@attributes` is not something that you ever use when interacting with the object itself).

The specific problem here is that it's trying to be helpful by choosing how best to represent the content of each element, such as a) just a string, b) an array of child elements, c) an object with an '@attributes' property contain attribute key-value pairse, etc. It doesn't have a format that contains both string content and attributes, so you don't get both in the output.

The solution, [as JustOnUnderMillions rightly says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39474057/157957), is to parse out the data you actually want into a structure of your choosing, which you can then `json_encode`. Something like this:

```
$comments = [];
$sx = simplexml_parse_string($xml);
foreach ( $sx->comment as $sx_comment ) {
    $comments[] = [
         // Extract text attributes as appropriate types
         'id' => (int)$sx_comment['id'],
         'user_id' => (int)$sx_comment['user'],
         // Make this one a boolean
         'active' => ( (int)$sx_comment['active'] == 1 ),
         // Maybe you want to format these as ISO 8601...
         'created_ts' => (int)$sx_comment['created'],
         'updated_ts' => (int)$sx_comment['updated'],
         // Extract text content as a string
         'text' => (string)$sx_comment
    ];
}
echo json_encode($comments);
```